# How to change the color of p-calendar on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I need to change the color of the p-calendar input box when it is clicked. By default is some shade of blue:
[image]

The date is invalid for me as it is in past. My code is taking care of that. So when i click outside that calendar i see my css taking place:

[image]

What else is required to change the color on highlight. Please mind that there are other calendars also on the same page. Their styling should not be disturbed. Here is what i tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div [class.turnRed]="invalidDate">
    <p-calendar (onInput)="onInput($event)"...></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
  invalidDate  : boolean = false;
  // logic for checking past date
  onInput(e) {
    const enteredDate = new Date(e.explicitOriginalTarget.value);
    var date = new Date();
    var Str = new Date(
      ('00' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        '/' +
        ('00' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
        '/' +
        date.getFullYear() +
        ' ' +
        ('00' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
        ':' +
        ('00' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
    );
    if (enteredDate.getTime() < Str.getTime()) {
      console.log('invalid date');
      this.invalidDate = true;
    } else {
      console.log('valid date');
      this.invalidDate = false;
    }
  }
```

**SCSS:**

```
.turnRed{
  border: solid #F70101 2.7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to your p-calendar element:

```
<div [class.turnRed]="invalidDate">
    <p-calendar (onInput)="onInput($event)" class="yourClass"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

then in your css/scss you can handle each event, e.g. hover and visited as below:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .yourClass {
    .p-inputtext:enabled:hover {
      background: cyan;
    }
    .p-inputtext:enabled:focus {
      background: purple;
    }
  }
}
```